# Best way to display private user information on a page in React

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, react-router

Suppose users can create private recipes. I was wondering how you could go about structuring a react app so that this would be possible so that only that user can see them.

I thought about doing a path like website/recipes/12345 but then would other people be able to access these urls if they were logged in?

Would it be better to have a general /recipes page, and then on that page load a specific recipe based on the data that was passed from the home page rather than have it embedded in the url? E.g. user clicks on 'chicken-burger' on main page and this takes them to /recipe but with 'chicken-burger' sent as a prop or something?

Comment: There's really not enough detail here for us to answer your question.  As it is it's extremely broad and there is no correct answer which makes it not a good fit for the site.  There are quite a few approaches that you could take.

Comment: The recipe will probably be stored in some database, accessed through some server, that's where the security should be handled. An authenticated user would be able to fetch the data while an unauthenticated user wouldn't, even if they had the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Structurally, for privacy, you will need to think about your backend more than anything else.

The structure of your React app isn't going to be the thing that keeps user's info private. If your backend is giving out data on endpoints that are supposed to be private, without authentication, then the data's not private no matter what your frontend is doing.

From what you've mentioned so far, I would take the react-router approach on the frontend and give each recipe its own path. Your backend should already be authenticating each request for a recipe to prevent other users from seeing their info.